# Allow only some cookies, and only as First Party (FF+IE)

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, cookies

Basically I want to disable all the cookies, except a few (white list).

The few that I want to allow, should only be allowed as first party, not third.

If I'm unchecking "Allow Cookies" in firefox, and add as exception a few sites, those sites have both first and third party cookies.

How can I allow only first party cookies for those site in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox cookie settings are found under Tools > Options > Privacy. Uncheck "Accept third-party cookies" and click OK.

To do so in Internet Explorer 8, click Tools > Internet Options > Privacy > Advanced. Select Block under Third-party Cookies and click OK twice.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you can try add-ons such as [Cookie Controller](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cookie-controller/) or [Cookie Monster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cookie-monster/):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: For IE I don't think there's anything similar available. There used to be a [No More Cookies](http://download.cnet.com/No-More-Cookies/3000-2144_4-10449885.html) add-on, but I don't think it offered the same level of fine-grained control and anyway, the site's disappeared and it's unlikely the add-on still works with new versions of the browser.